# floor-then-convert_int vs convert_int_rtn - equivalent in OpenCL?

Tags: floating-point, type-conversion, opencl

In OpenCL, is:

```
convert_int(floor(my_float))
```

exactly equivalent to

```
convert_int_rtn(my_float)
```

semantically? Would I ever prefer the former command to the latter?

If you answer depends on the fact that I've chosen `int`, try to generalize it to an arbitrary integer types `T`.

Notes:

- OpenCL 1.2 [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/convert_T.html) for `convert_T`.
- `_rtn` means "round to negative infinity".

Comment: Speaking to floating-point, not OpenCL specifications, `floor(−¼)` is −1, so converting it to an integer with truncation or round-to-nearest will yield a different result (−1) than converting −¼ (0).  You may want `trunc` rather than `floor`. Then, a correct `trunc` implementation has no error, since it merely removes (changes to zero) digits in the floating-point representation. If the `OpenCL` conversion to integer truncates, then that conversion has the same effect has truncating in floating-point and then converting. For a round-to-nearest conversion, truncating first cannot work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: `_rtn` is round to negative infinity.

Comment: Okay, then the proposed operations are the same, as far as the floating-point semantics are concerned,

Answer (score 0):

A floor operation followed by a conversion to integer with any rounding mode always produces the same result as a conversion to integer with rounding toward −∞.

Proof for numbers within the integer range:

- If x is positive, its floor is representable merely by zeroing base-b digits in the floating-point representation, where b is the base used in the representation.
- If x is negative, its floor either has the same base-b exponent e in the representation or one greater. If it is the same, the floor is representable since the bits required for its representation are a subset of the significant bits of x. It it is greater, the floor is representable since it is exactly −b<sup>e+1</sup>. (Here we assume that does not round to −∞, which is possible with a floating-point format with an abnormally tiny exponent range and/or an abnormally wide significand.)
- If the floor of x is representable in the destination integer format, then converting it to integer produces it (using any rounding mode for the conversion, since there will be no rounding). Similarly, converting x to integer with rounding to −∞ will produce the same value, the floor of x.

If the floor of x is not representable, whether the two conversions to integer produce the same result may depend upon their specifications for overflow.

Comment: I realize that the operations are _theoretically_ equivalent. The question is whether their OpenCL semantics will conform with this fact...